# How to create template decorator

Tags: templates, fastapi, decorator

I see that the normal way render response template in FastAPI takes more steps. So how can I create a decorator that will accept template file and help render the template on return.

For example here is the normal way to render a template file

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='app/public/templates')

@app.get('/')
def index(request: Request, user_id: str | None):
    if user_id:
        context = {'request':request, 'user_id':user_id}
        return template.TemplateResponse('index1.html', context=context)
    else:
        context = {'request':request}
        return template.TemplateResponse('index2.html', context=context)
```

I already have an answer to my question, I just want to share it to public for my future use or if anyone might be interested in it

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. The `response_template` accept list of template files and an optional `default_index`, the view can change the default_index by returning a dict with template_index set.

```
from functools import wraps
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='app/public/templates')

def response_template(template_list: list[str], default_index=0):
    def wrapper(function):
        @wraps(function)
        async def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            result = await function(*args, **kwargs)
            if isinstance(result, dict):
                template_index = result.pop('template_index', default_index)
                return templates.TemplateResponse(template_list[template_index], context=result)
            else:
                return result
        return inner
    return wrapper

@app.get('/')
@response_template(['index1.html', 'index2.html'])
async def index(request: Request, user_id: str | None):
    if user_id:
        return {'request':request, 'user_id': user_id}
    else:
        return {'request':request, 'template_index': 1}
```